# Connect via SSH through JSch with encrypted indentiy and without passphrase

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I'm writing some software that will be scheduled to SFTP files between servers every so often. I'm currently having trouble connecting to remote servers with JSch.

I believe this stems from the fact that the account my program is running as has it's private SSH key encrypted with a passphrase.

The following code:

```
    public SFTPDelivery(Environment environment) throws Exception {
        super(environment);
        String userName = System.getProperty("user.name");
        String userDir = System.getProperty("user.home");

        jsch.addIdentity(userDir + "//.ssh//id_rsa");
        jsch.setKnownHosts(userDir + "//.ssh//known_hosts");

        session = jsch.getSession(userName, environment.getRemoteServer(), 22);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "yes");
        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
        session.connect();

        channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
    }
```

throws:

```
    com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: USERAUTH fail
        at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPublicKey.start(UserAuthPublicKey.java:119)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:463)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
        at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.SFTPDelivery.<init>(SFTPDelivery.java:30)
```

JSch is expecting a passphrase to be passed in with encrypted identities. For security, I can't hard code the passphrase.

The idea is that the program would run as `QualAccount` on `QualServer`, and tries to connect via SSH to `QualAccount` on `DevServer`. JSch fails because `QualAccount`'s id_rsa is encrypted and the required passphrase isn't included.

The reason I'm writing a question for this is because from QualAccount's terminal I am able to SSH into the the other account/server without any password/passphrase prompt.

So is there a way for JSch to not require a passphrase for encrypted identities if the account already has the necessary SSH permissions to connect via the terminal?

Thanks.

Comment: If the id_rsa truly has a password then I'm surprised the addIdentity call doesn't fail immediately. Please check the id_rsa at the top of the file you should see whether the key is encrypted (should actually have ENCRYPTED somewhere at the top). If it is encrypted then the fact that you don't need to enter a password wen logged into QualAccount would be indicative of some kind of ssh-agent forwarding or it's being initialized at login (which typically would require a password unless there was keychain usage).

Comment: Thanks for the input! 
id_rsa is encrypted: Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED.
I

Comment: Please check "ssh-add -l" to see what the loaded identities are when logged into the "QualAccount's terminal"

Comment: "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

Comment: Can you echo "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" for me as well please from the terminal

Comment: The variable is empty.

Comment: Well, the confusing thing here is that simply being logged in as QualAccount wouldn't decrypt the id_rsa magically so that it could be used for logging into the DevServer. At some the key needs to be decrypted and it would either be stored into the ssh-agent (memory), forwarded (in which case you would be logging into QualAccount on QualServer and it would be forwarded but the SSH_AUTH_SOCK would be defined), or you should be prompted when you connect to DevServer.

Comment: I was wrong. The id_rsa for DevAccount was encrypted but the id_rsa for QualAccount was not encrypted. My issue is resolved. Thanks for your help though.